# Bayesian Statistics: Derivation of the expected value of the posterior predictive distribution

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am reading the Gelman, et. al., book *Bayesian Data Analysis* and they talk about the expected value of the posterior predictive distribution as follows. However, they did not really seem to derive this in the book itself. I was hoping someone could help fill in the gaps.

I am talking about p.41 of section 2.5. The claim is that:

$$
\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | y)=\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y) | y)=\mathrm{E}(\theta | y)=\mu_{1}
$$

and

$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{var}(\tilde{y} | y) &=\mathrm{E}(\operatorname{var}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y) | y)+\operatorname{var}(\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y) | y) \\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(\sigma^{2} | y\right)+\operatorname{var}(\theta | y) \\
&=\sigma^{2}+\tau_{1}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\tilde{y}$ is the predicted distribution for a new data point. The distribtion for $y$ is normal, so conjugacy probably plays a roll here.

The thing that was confusing me was how $\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y) | y)=\mathrm{E}(\theta | y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this analysis (for the normal distribution with known variance) is not particularly well explained in the book. Looking at why $\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y) | y)=\mathrm{E}(\theta | y)$, first consider $\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y)$.

By definition of the assumed model, two observations $y$ and $\tilde{y}$ are independent conditional on the value of $\theta$. If you know $\theta$, knowledge of $y$ will tell you nothing more about $\tilde{y}$. So $\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y)=\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta)$. This value is the expected value of a normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2$ i.e. $\theta$. So $\mathrm{E}(\tilde{y} | \theta, y)=\theta$.

There's a brief discussion on the posterior predictive distribution in Section 1.3 of the book, page 7.

Comment: @S yes, thanks so much for this. The intuition you provided makes perfect sense, but the notation of an expectation within an expectation was throwing me off. I totally get it now. I also looked at the Bishop book on Pattern Recognition... and that helped clarify the point. Thanks again for your help.